# Select subset of dataframe based collected in the last N unique dates

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to filter a dataframe such that I retain all data from the last N unique days in the dataset, not including NA's. My data is not collected on any known frequency - some days might contain 100 datapoints and then no data for weeks. The end goal is to do a regression analysis with respect to time, based on most recent data available. If I just do a tail function and pick last N rows (arranged by date), I sometimes get all data from 1-2 days, which doesn't lend itself to a good regression wrt time.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

The data looks like attached. The only thing I attempted is tail(df, 30) function as below and then did the linear regression, which is when I realized the results looked odd because I apparently had more than 30 data points on 12/11.

```
all_data2 <- all_data2 %>%
        filter(!!sym(test_par[j]) < upper_q, !!sym(test_par[j]) > lower_q ) %>%
        mutate(week=difftime(code_date, as.Date(x_start), units = c("weeks")))

      all_data2 <- all_data2 %>%
        mutate(test_par_avg=SMA(all_data2[test_par[j]], n=nsmooth)) %>%
        filter(!is.na(test_par_avg)) %>%
        arrange(code_date) %>%
        tail(no_tail)
      
       model <- lm(test_par_avg ~ week, data=all_data2)
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you could share some test data with us, and also show us what you've attempted already.

Comment: Please share sample data as copy/pasteable text so that we can test code and demonstrate solutions on it, not as a picture. `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` will give us a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of data, including all class and structure information. Please choose a suitable small subset to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
my_df <- data.frame("Date" = c("01/01/2021", "01/01/2021", "02/02/2021", "03/03/2021", "03/05/2021", NA, "03/03/2021"),
                "Value" = c(2, NA, NA, 2, 4, 4, 1),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df <- my_df[complete.cases(my_df),]
my_df <- my_df %>% group_by(dmy(Date)) %>% mutate(ID = cur_group_id())

my_number <- 2
my_value <- sort(unique(my_df$ID))
my_value <- tail(my_value, my_number)
my_var <- which(my_df$ID %in% my_value)
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_df <- my_df[my_var,]
}
```

So first complete.cases allow us to keep all rows that don't have any NA value.

Then we assign an unique ID for all unique Date value.

After the last part is for selecting the N unique days so here N = 2.

Comment: great, thanks. I think that is what I am looking for - I will try and let you know either way.